# MassTransit Saga: what is correct way to inject scoped services?

Tags: asp.net-core, masstransit, saga

I have asp .net core 3.1 app and Masstransit 7.2.2.
I have a Saga, inside which I have to use scoped services. Now I inject IServiceProvider and manually create needed objects:

```
using var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope();
var myService1 = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMyService1>();
var myService2 = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMyService2>();
```

If I need `IMyService1` and `IMyService2` in different steps of saga I have to write the same code in each of them because I should to dispose `scope` object.

Is this the only approach or are there other approaches?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use dependencies in a state machine, you must create a [custom activity](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/sagas/automatonymous.html#custom). The activity will be resolved from the container within the scope created for the saga.